# JPA: Several table to one Entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table1

```
ID | RECORD | DATE | NAME ...
```

and a table2

```
ID | RECORD | DATE | CITY ...
```

And I have a POJO **Table1.java** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class Table1{
private String id = null;
private String record = null;
private Date date = null;
private String name = null;
...
}
```

Then I execute query like this:

```
...
String q = "select * from table1"
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(q, Table1.class);
return new ArrayList<Table1>(query.getResultList());
...
```

I need join table1 and table2 (primary key = ID, RECORD, DATE) and add field **CITY** from **table2** add to **Table1** class.
How can I do this?

Comment: both table are related or not?how do you want to join them?

Comment: @singhakash yes, related. Join: (table1.id = table2.id and table1.record = table2.record and table1.date = table2.date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using JPA here but looking for an SQL query. While this is obviously possible in SQL, if we want to remain in the domain of JPA then we can do this using the `@SecondaryTable` functionality which allows you to map 1 Entity to 2 (or more) tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@SecondaryTable(name="table2")
    public class Table1{

    //by default these are mapped to T1
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String record;
    private Date date;
    private String name ;

    //explicitly specify the table to map to T2
    @Column(table="table2")
    private String city:

}
```

As you have mapped at the Entity level you don't really need a query, viz. city just becomes a property of your Entity with the SQL join done transparently behind the scenes.

```
EntityManager em = //;
Table1 t1 = em.find(T1.class, 1);
System.out.println(t1.getCity());
```

See the below for further information:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Comment: What should be an query?

Comment: You don't really need a query. You have mapped it at the entity level so every time you load an instance the field will be populated for you viz. the JPA provider will do the join for you behind the scenes.

Comment: a perfect answer, on a side note, if @Diooi still wants to use `createNativeQuery` then you need to use `SqlResultSetMappings`, more information, just google it up.

Comment: @AlanHay I use Entity in another place and can't add additional Column in Entity, can I do this with Transient?

Comment: @tbc  I use Entity in another place and can't add additional Column in Entity, can I do this with Transient?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. Why couldn't you add another field against an existing DB column?

Comment: @AlanHay there are some special cases where you can't change existing code, it's so much retesting for nothing.

Comment: @Diooi you don't need to change anything if you use Mapping, since the result is an array of entities / columns that conform to the mapping definition